# Shopping Cart with Vue and Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have cloned this awesome shopping cart repo from https://github.com/vueschool/learn-vuex, it works good but doesn't handle data for my use case. For anyone who has used this repo, how do i extend it by getting products from database or Api?

Shop.js

```
const _products = [
{"id": 1, "title": "iPad 4 Mini", "price": 500.01, "inventory": 2},
{"id": 2, "title": "H&M T-Shirt White", "price": 10.99, 
"inventory": 10},
{"id": 3, "title": "Charli XCX - Sucker CD", "price": 19.99, 
"inventory": 5}
  ]

export default {
getProducts (cb) {
    setTimeout(() => cb(_products), 100)
   },
buyProducts (products, cb, errorCb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
    // simulate random checkout failure.
    (Math.random() > 0.5 || 
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('PhantomJS') > -1)
    ? cb()
    : errorCb()
}, 100)
 }
}
```

Shop gets called via vuex actions

```
actions: {
   fetchProducts({commit}) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // make the call
    // call setProducts mutation
    shop.getProducts(products => {
      commit('setProducts', products)
      resolve()
    })
  })
 }
```

Comment: Where is `then` after a Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `axios` to make a call to the server and get products like following

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: {},
    },
    actions: {
        getProducts({commit},data) {
            axios.get(`api/product?page=`+ data.page + '&orderBy='+ data.orderBy).then((response) => {
            commit('updateProducts', response.data);
        })
    },
    mutations: {
        updateProducts (state, products) {
            state.products = products
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: any idea on pagination?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Pass `page` from component

Comment: Thanks, i've tried to use your code but i get 'page is undefined', you can respond here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988462/pagination-in-vuex-store