# Pagination in Vuex Store

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have cloned this awesome shopping cart repo from https://github.com/vueschool/learn-vuex, and i get data like this:

```
ProductList.vue

<template>
    <div>
<ul>
        <li v-for="product in products">
           - {{product.name}} - {{product.price}}
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        fetchProducts: 'products/fetchProducts'
      })
    }
</script>

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: {},
    },
    actions: {
    fetchProducts({commit},data) {
            axios.get(`api/product`).then((response) => {
            commit('updateProducts', response.data);
        })
    },
    mutations: {
        updateProducts (state, products) {
            state.products = products
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to paginate results and need help in that direction, do i need to create a pagination state or new module in the vuex store, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you dont need a new module for pagination, you can just send pagination data trough data property in method action, like totalPage, and currentPage

Comment: Show some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

I use one of the `RenderlessLaravelVuePagination` component for pagination.

```
<pagination :data="products" @pagination-change-page="getProducts"></pagination>
```

and remaining code is below

```
export default {
  name: 'ProductList',
  mounted() {
    this.getProducts();
  },
  methods: {
    getProducts(page = 1){
      this.$store.dispatch('getProducts',{
        page: page
    });
  },
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: i took out the data from vuex, i wasn't comfortable with storing all that data in vuex as it gets large over time. I'll be using your solution just without vuex. Thanks.

Comment: @LDUBBS you can create separate files and models over time. Main advantage is single source of data.

Comment: Trying this again Mike, i'm still not able to apply your solution to mapped states and actions.

Comment: Post your code here please, are you using any plugin for `pagination` or doing it yourself? Post your controller code as well.

Comment: Sort of moved it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58106049/paginating-items-from-vuex-store

Answer (score 0):

You need to define meta object in order to store the meta data returning from your axio post. Then, you can use that meta object in your vue.

Do something like this:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        products: {},
        productsMeta: {}

    },
    actions: {
        getProducts({commit},data) {
            axios.get(`api/product`).then(response => {
            this.productsMeta = response.meta;
            }).commit('updateProducts', response.data);
        })
    },
    mutations: {
        updateProducts (state, products) {
            state.products = products
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works too but something weird happens when i add products to cart. Only the first item is added.